# what is the output of console.log(+32)?

Tags: javascript, console.log

Does javascript skips "+" symbol for certain functions?
Please find the below code

```js
console.log(+32)
```

Why do we get the output from console as 32?

Answer (score 5):

`+` will try parse your `variable/value` into the `number`. 
So if you want to get `+32` in the console, you need to work with `strings`.

See an example
In the first case variables are concatenated, because one of them is a string.
In the second case, I first parse `a` into the number with `+` operator and get the sum of two numbers.

```js
var a = '1';
var b = 2;

console.log(a + b);
console.log( (+a) + b);
```

Comment: @Ashok if this helps you, you can mark as correct and help others to find it easily